# Importing class from another directory to Flask App routes/views

Tags: python-3.x, flask, wsgi

I have a flask application, I used the below to import a module I wrote into the forms.py file and it seems to work.

```
sys.path.append('/home/user/lib/')
from mymodule import *
```

However when I attempt to import it into my routes.py file it fails. When I restart my WSGI apache server it will not load, unfortunately I don't get any logs telling why for some reason.

Below is the layout of my application.

```
flaskapp
├── config.py
├── forms.py
├── flaskapp.wsgi
├── __init__.py
├── routes.py
├── static
│   ├── search.js
│   └── sort.js
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    ├── certs_view.html
    ├── results.html
    ├── index.html
    ├── new_org.html
    ├── submit_csr.html
    └── upload.html
```

I have tried the append, and insert methods to try an import the module without any success. I even created a symbolic link to try it that way but the WSGI server won't load as soon as I attempt to import that into the routes.py.

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import flaskapp.routes
import flaskapp.config
import flaskapp.forms
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flaskapp.forms import RequestCSRForm
from flaskapp.forms import SubmitForm
from flaskapp.forms import UploadCertificate
from flaskapp.forms import CreateNewOrg
#from mymodule import *
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = ''
app.config.from_object(config)
...
```

config.py

```
import os
from flaskapp import app
...
```

!This One Works!
forms.py

```
import sys, json
from flaskapp import app
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField, TextAreaField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
sys.path.append('/home/user/lib/')
from mymodule import *
...
```

!This One DOESN'T Works!
routes.py

```
import os, datetime, json, time, OpenSSL.crypto
from flaskapp import app
from flask import render_template, Flask, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flaskapp.forms import RequestCSRForm
from flaskapp.forms import SubmitForm
from flaskapp.forms import UploadCertificate
from flaskapp.forms import CreateNewOrg
from OpenSSL.crypto import load_certificate_request, FILETYPE_PEM
sys.path.append('/home/user/lib')
from mymodule import *
...
```

I want to be able to call functions from mymodule from the routes.py or ideal all of them...

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a setup to your module, then `pip install mymodule` in the venv of your flaskapp?

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/